# Pandas regex replacement when there is no match

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm using [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to extract numbers from strings (its data that has been scraped from [@WPWeather](https://twitter.com/WPWeather)) and have got the point where I've extracted all the fields into a DataFrame like this...

```
 df.head()
Out[48]: 
                              temp   pressure relative_humidity  \
created_at                                                        
2019-12-13 10:19:13  5.2\xc2\xbaC,   975.4mb,            91.3%.   
2019-12-12 10:19:07    2\xc2\xbaC,   990.3mb,            96.9%.   
2019-12-11 10:19:07  4.2\xc2\xbaC,  1000.8mb,            85.7%.   
2019-12-10 10:19:00  6.3\xc2\xbaC,  1008.5mb,            94.4%.   
2019-12-09 10:18:51  5.4\xc2\xbaC,  1006.7mb,            68.5%.   

                    last_24_max_temp last_24_min_temp      rain sunshine  
created_at                                                                
2019-12-13 10:19:13      7\xc2\xbaC,      2\xc2\xbaC,    9.5mm,        0  
2019-12-12 10:19:07      6\xc2\xbaC,    1.5\xc2\xbaC,   0.9mm.'      NaN  
2019-12-11 10:19:07   11.7\xc2\xbaC,    2.2\xc2\xbaC,  14.1mm.'      NaN  
2019-12-10 10:19:00    6.5\xc2\xbaC,    1.9\xc2\xbaC,   1.1mm.'      NaN  
2019-12-09 10:18:51    8.5\xc2\xbaC,    5.2\xc2\xbaC,    1.5mm,      1.9
```

I'm trying to use regex's to extract the numerical values using...

```
pd.to_numeric(df['temp'].str.replace(r'(^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)', r'\1', regex=True))
```

...and it works well but I've hit an instance where one of the temperature fields doesn't have a value and is simply `\xc2\xbaC,`, as a consequence there is nothing matched in the first grouping to use in `r'\1'` and when it gets to trying to convert to numeric it fails with...

```
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "\xc2\xbaC," at position 120
```

How do I replace non-matches with something sane such as blank so that when I then call `pd.to_numeric()` it will convert to `NaN`?

Comment: Is possible use `pd.to_numeric(df['temp'].str.replace(r'\xc2\xbaC', '', regex=True))` ?

Comment: I'm trying to be as generic as possible as there are some other strange things that have cropped up during the scraping as an artifact of using `encode('utf-8'), for example there are some `\xc2\xb0` so rather than guess at everything that exists or might crop up in the future I wanted to use a regex to get the first number (whether thats negative, int or decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde idea is change string for replace, then got not exist values get missing values:

```
df['temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['temp'].str.replace(r'\xc2\xbaC,', '', regex=True))
print (df)
                     temp   pressure relative_humidity
created_at                                            
2019-12-13 10:19:13   5.2   975.4mb,            91.3%.
2019-12-12 10:19:07   2.0   990.3mb,            96.9%.
2019-12-11 10:19:07   4.2  1000.8mb,            85.7%.
2019-12-10 10:19:00   6.3  1008.5mb,            94.4%.
2019-12-09 10:18:51   5.4  1006.7mb,            68.5%.
```

Your solution should be changed with parameter `errors='coerce'` in [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace non numeric to missing values:

```
df['temp'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['temp'].str.replace(r'(^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)',r'\1',regex=True),
                            errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: D'oh I'd completely forgotten to actually read the `to_numeric()` page, had I done so I'd have likely clocked the `errors='coerce'` option.  Thank you.